# Override toDataURL(), toBlob() and getImageData()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, html5-canvas, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am attempting to develop a web extension that protects people against browser fingerprinting and I am working on the canvas API at the moment. I need to 'spoof' or 'fake' the image data that is returned from the following methods to prevent [canvas fingerprinting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_fingerprinting):

HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL() - [toDataURL() Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL)

HTMLCanvasElement.toBlob() - [toBlob() Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob)

CanvasRenderingContext2D.getImageData() - [getImageData() Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData)

And possible more ... But lets start with these. I am using javascript prototypes to override methods. toDataURL() returns a fake output which is good however toBlob() and getImageData() both still return the same value which is also the real output, not what I want :(

The repository is on [github](https://github.com/Snapper26/shapeshifter).

This [canvas.js](https://github.com/Snapper26/shapeshifter/blob/master/js/api/canvas.js) file contains my code that attempts to add 1 to every byte in the array which is in RGBA format. Yes I know this is terrible, its only for testing. I will use random numbers for the real thing but at the moment I am just trying to get it to return a value that is different from the default so that a hash of the pixel data or image data would be different.

Any ideas??? If you need additional info or do not understand somethning please ask me or let me know. Thanks ...

Comment: Sorry I won't go to your external repo to check for what you did wrong. You probably know that some extensions already do that. Why don't you check how they did ?

Comment: This is some sort of joke? I read up on it, but what are they really tracking, your finger movement. It's their website. What gives?

Comment: @PHPglue you know privacy ? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_fingerprinting

Comment: Any movement can be tracked using AJAX. There's no need for canvas, in order to do the tracking. Looks like a cool way to authenticate users. Create some random canvas image. Have info stored on the Sever to test against your movements, and see if you're not a robot.

Comment: @PHPglue No it's not a joke. Browser fingerprinting is a metaphor for tracking a collection of browser attributes which makes up a possibly unique browser configuration that can be used to track you. It doesn't literally mean tracking your organic finger movements on the screen of a mobile device. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: But it's not to check if you are a human, it's to register your computer as an unique one.

Comment: Yes like Kaiido said, it can be used to track you which is the problem

Comment: @Kaiido yes I am aware that others do it like random agent spoofer, one which I have looked over the source many times. It's not that it doesn't work at all, toDataURL() does work whereas toBlob() doesn't seem to despite having being implemented in the same way. Would you prefer me to post source code here?

Comment: Yes, questions on SO should be self-contained. But in your case I would even split it in two questions : one with `toBlob`'s problem, and one with `getImageData`'s one. Also note that context2D finger-printing has realtively small entropy, webgl one has way more. And if you don't do anything for all the other finger-printing methods, your plugin won't be of too much help (it's bettter to know you're nude, than going in a bike race in underwear while you thought you had the right suit).

Comment: I'm not seeing any Privacy or Security Risk. I'm not buying it.

Comment: @Kaiido Ok thanks for the advice. I will redo the question. I like your analogy about the bike race. I am planning to spoof WebGL as well but first I need to do the 2d canvas.

Comment: @PHPglue The privacy problem posed here is that as long as your browser fingerprint (combined from many aspects of your browser including user agent, fonts, plugins, canvas, audio stack etc) stays the same, different websites can 'track' you as you move between websites and also re identify you when you reconnect to a site you previously visited even if you don't log in. This allows advertising and analytics companies to 'rebuild' your browsing history and either sell it or use it to advertise to you or sell you stuff. Whether this bothers you or not is another matter entirely.

Comment: @Kaiido I have made a new question available at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43626113/overriding-canvasrenderingcontext2d-getimagedata