# Overriding CanvasRenderingContext2D.getImageData()

Tags: javascript, canvas, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am trying to override the built in method CanvasRenderingContext2D.getImageData(). I would like to override the implementation so that the modified function uses the canvas context to modify the canvas and then calls the original function which should return different data that if the function was not overridden. The reason I am doing this is to prevent browser fingerprinting.

canvas.js

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    var originalGetImageData = CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.getImageData;

    // This function just adds 1 to each RGBA component in the array for testing.
    // Will add random values for the real thing.
    function randomiseImageData(image) {        
        var imageData = image.data;

        var imageLength = imageData.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < imageLength; i++) {
            imageData[i] += 1;
        }

        var modifiedImage = new ImageData(image.width, image.height);

        return modifiedImage;
    }

    CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.getImageData = function(sx, sy, sw, sh) {
        console.log("[ALERT] " + window.location.hostname + " called CanvasRenderingContext2D.getImageData()");

        const origin = window.location.hostname;

        Math.seedrandom(origin);

        var image = originalGetImageData.call(this, sx, sy, sw, sh);

        return randomiseImageData(image);
    };
})();
```

Comment: Introducing an additional level of entropy to the content of the canvas will simply make the browser more unique thus significantly easier to identify and track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a new **empty** ImageData object.

I guess what you want is to return the filled one.
Since you already modified the `data` array, you can simply return the original ImageData, your modifications will have been made.

```js
// shortened version
(function(){
 const ori = CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.getImageData;
 CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.getImageData = function(){
  let imageData = ori.apply(this, arguments);
  // modify the Uint8Array
  imageData.data.forEach((v, i, a) => a[i]+=1);
  // return the now modified ImageData
  return imageData;
  };
 })()
 
var ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
console.log(ctx.getImageData(0,0,1,1));
```

If you really want to create a new ImageData, then it's

```
new ImageData(imageData, image.width, image.height);
//             ^^
//           pass the data to fill the new ImageData object
```

But note that browser support is not great, and that you won't win anything by doing so.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem was in my code I was using for testing the fingerprint, not the code I was using to fake the fingerprint. Its all fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

### You can not remove the fingerprint.

For more [The Web never forgets](https://securehomes.esat.kuleuven.be/%7Egacar/persistent/index.html)

You can not circumvent fingerprinting. The best you can do is return the most common fingerprint (which is not easily ascertained) increasing the set of devices you may belong to.

Returning a random set of pixels (or incrementing each pixel channel by one) is about the worst you can do if you are the only one doing it. It would absolutly mark your browser as unique and would let traking software know that the browser that returns changed data is just one, or one of a very small set.

The best way to stop fingerprinting is via a common and widely adopted data return strategy. If every browser returned all zero (transparent black) then there would be no uniqueness and thus no way to track the device based on the canvas.

Canvas fingerprinting is only part of a fingerprint, there are many more sources of data the help identify a device. The browser, browser version, OS, OS version, screen resolution, and a long list of others. Even if you eliminate the canvas as a source of uniqueness it is pointless unless you do the same with the rest of the information.

#### Mitigation

So with that said the code to return zeroed data is as follows.

```
(function () {
    if (window.CanvasRenderingContext2D) {
        const gid = CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.getImageData;
        CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.getImageData = function (x, y, w, h) {
            var data = gid.bind(this)(x, y, w, h);
            data.data.fill(0);  // fill with zero
            return data;
        }
        // Token way to avoid JS from finding out that you have overwritten the prototype overwrite
        // the toString method as well (note ctx.getImageData.toString.toString() will
        // still show you have changed the prototype but over writing Object.toSting is not worth the problems)
        CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.getImageData.toString = function () {
            return "function getImageData() { [native code] }";
        }
    }
}());
```

Comment: I agree with the part about adding 1 to every pixel being bad. Perhaps I should have made it more clear that is only for testing, I will come up with something better later. I also agree that you cannot prevent fingerprinting, however what I intend to do is rather change my fingerprint on a per site and session basis. In this case it shouldn't matter how unique or common my fingerprint is. Please let me know if you disagree.

Comment: Canvas fingerprinting uses the unique way each browser (and browser version) renders text. To simulate another browser you will need to know the font, font size, font alignment, text used, text style, background pixels, etc for each browser, all of which will be unique to each fingerprinting service. You could capture the finger print for each browser, and replace the rendered finger print with the copy, but a smarter finger print would make that impractical (if they detected a counter print). Unless you use a different proxy every time you navigate you are being tracked.

Comment: Agreed with all of that. So how about introducing say cryptographic random noise into the image different for each site and session? Since the rendered text is just pixel data at the end.

Comment: @Snapper26 Again this would be unique, if I wrote a finger printing service, any such anomalous returns would be marked for further investigation, it would not take long to work out only one user is returning random. You would go one of a large set monitored by machines  to one of a set of one under a microscope with human eyes. Just use one browser for sites x,y,z and another for sites you dont want associated.